# Selenium RC Automation "Element Not found error"

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, xpath

Selenium RC Automation `"Element Not found error"`

I am presently automating my project. However when playing back the script I am getting element not found error for a button. I copied XPATH of the button from the firebug

The XPATH is as follows got from firebug:

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/form/table/tbody/tr[23]/td[2]/input
```

So I wrote in code:

```
Selenium.click("xpath=/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/form/table/tbody/tr[23]/td[2]/input");
```

Still I am getting the same error as element not found

Comment: Which language are u writing in

Comment: I am using Java. I copied script from selenium IDE in JUnit 4

Comment: Could you provide the html code for your page?

Comment: It's too big to paste it here. What part of html page do u want me to copy?

Comment: The Xpath I have got is ".//*[@id='bgcontainer']/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form/table/tbody/tr[23]/td[2]/input" for button "Continue"                                                           but when I use it in code                                         i.e. selenium.click("xpath=.//*[@id='bgcontainer']/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form/table/tbody/tr[23]/td[2]/input");                                                           I get error that element not found. Please help it's urgent

Comment: Here is html code associated with the button which is causing error                                                             <td colspan="3" align="right">
        <!--<input type="submit" value=" " style="height:37;width:138;background-image:url('../../images/btn_continue.jpg');border:none">-->
        <input type="submit" value=" " onclick="return checkField();" class="btncontinue">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using css path and check. Still, if this is not working, try to use the selenium command

selenium.isElementPresent("id or xpath or css of your continue button");

and check if the element is present in the web page.

Also make sure that the Continue button is not present inside any other frames.